# How to append some data to a file in Julia?

Tags: julia

I have a text file and I want to append some string to it without writing over the existing data. How can I accomplish this in Julia?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Julia provides a bunch of different options to accomplish this same goal. One possible option is to do:

```
# Open file in append mode and then write to it
exampleFileIOStream =  open("example.txt","a")

write(exampleFileIOStream, "Hello world!");
```

You can read the [full docs for the open function](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/io-network/#Base.open) and the corresponding functionality in the Julia docs.